# How to force Image Tooltip to be display on top of other tooltips?

Tags: html, css

I have a **CSS Image Tooltip** that when hover it will display another big image tooltip.

Now, when i hover and i have another tooltip (small) image near the tooltip, i get that result:

[image]

As you can see, the big tooltip is display **under** the second tooltip (small) image.

I want to force it to display **above** that small tooltip.

Here is the HTML code:

```css
.maptt {
  margin-left: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 97px;
  z-index: 200;
  position: absolute;
}
.mapttlish {
  margin-left: 450px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 197px;
  z-index: 200;
  position: absolute;
}
/* NewTooltip */

a.tooltip1 {
  outline: none;
}
a.tooltip1 strong {
  line-height: 30px;
}
a.tooltip1:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.tooltip1 span {
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: 28px;
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 16px;
}
a.tooltip1:hover span {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  color: #111;
  border: 1px solid #DCA;
  background: #fffAF0;
}
.callout {
  z-index: 20;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  border: 0;
  left: -12px;
}
/*CSS3 extras*/

a.tooltip1 span {
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="maptt">

  <!-- tooltip1-->
  <a href="#" class="tooltip1">
    <img src="http://coreneto.com/delete/hover.png" />
    <span>
        <img class="callout" />
        <img src="http://coreneto.com/delete/hover-big.png" style="float:right;" /><strong style="font-size:16px;">First</strong>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="mapttlish">

  <!-- tooltip2-->
  <a href="#" class="tooltip1">
    <img src="http://coreneto.com/delete/hover.png" />
    <span>
        <img class="callout" />
        <img src="http://coreneto.com/delete/hover-big.png" style="float:right;" /><strong style="font-size:16px;">Second</strong>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is a live one: [**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/zyraqtsz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a `z-index` issue. Add the right `z-index` to `a.tooltip1:hover span` and give `z-index` `auto` to `.maptt`:

```
a.tooltip1 span,
a.tooltip1:hover span {
  z-index: 9999;
}
.maptt {
  z-index: auto;
}
```

**Preview**

[image: before]

[image: aftert]

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zogbs35w/**